# Native Messaging host tried sending a message that is 460151579 bytes long

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When using the native messaging API for Google Chrome it is an advantage to run chrome from terminal so by which one can read messages printed to stderr by both chrome and one's native application.

For some reason this causes Chrome to hickup with something as in:

```
[22173:22201:1202/134930:ERROR:native_message_process_host.cc(271)] \
Native Messaging host tried sending a message that is 460151579 bytes long.
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround for this is to redirect stderr to a file.

To be able to view this log in real-time one solution is:

```
$ google-chrome 2> >(tee stderr.log >&2)
```